Remote Login Notifications: SSHD + PAM + MSMTP/GMX on Ubuntu and Ubuntu-like Systems in 2024
I wanted to setup e-mail notifications to the gmail account I use for work. I spent all day playing with sendmail, exim4, sendemail, nullmailer, dma, etc., and I finally have a working solution. SSH+PAM turned out to be trivial. The blockage was finding a simple mailing solution (that ideally doesn't conflict with whatever is currently running on :25).

This is a question and answer site. This does not read as a question and is therefore off topic.

You can read the info on this link to see how to ask a proper question. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

#! /usr/bin/env bash
set -euxo nounset -o pipefail
(( ! $# ))
(( ! UID ))

apt update
apt install -y msmtp # install the email client of your choice

[[ -f ~/.msmtprc ]] ||
cat >   ~/.msmtprc << "EOF"
# Default settings
defaults
auth    on
tls    on
tls_trust_file    /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
logfile ~/.msmtp.log

# gmx
account  gmx          # GMX is a little easier to integrate with things like slack,
host     smtp.gmx.net # so when sending *from* gmail didn't work,
port     587          # I fell back to GMX
from     me@gmx.com   # change this, obviously
user     me@gmx.com
password gmx-password # change this too

account default : gmx
EOF
chmod -v 0500 ~/.msmtprc # it might complain about permissions because the file has secrets

# now just follow the instructions
# https://medium.com/@alessandrocuda/ssh-login-alerts-with-sendmail-and-pam-3ef53aca1381

[[ -d    /etc/pam.scripts ]] ||
mkdir -v /etc/pam.scripts
chmod -v 0755 /etc/pam.scripts

[[ -f /etc/pam.scripts/ssh_alert.sh ]] ||
cat > /etc/pam.scripts/ssh_alert.sh << "FOE"
#!/bin/sh

# Your Email Information: Recipient (To:), Subject and Body
RECIPIENT="your-supers-email@gmail.com" # change it
SUBJECT="Email from your Server: SSH Alert"

BODY="
A SSH login was successful, so here are some information for security:
        User:        $PAM_USER
        User IP Host: $PAM_RHOST
        Service:     $PAM_SERVICE
        TTY:         $PAM_TTY
        Date:        `date`
        Server:      `uname -a`
"

if [ ${PAM_TYPE} = "open_session" ]; then
# the emails weren't sending right, so I changed this
msmtp -a gmx ${RECIPIENT} << EOF
Subject: ${SUBJECT}

${BODY}
EOF
fi

exit 0
FOE
chmod -v 0700 /etc/pam.scripts/ssh_alert.sh

grep -q '^# SSH Alert script' /etc/pam.d/sshd ||
cat >>                        /etc/pam.d/sshd << "EOF"

# SSH Alert script
session required pam_exec.so /etc/pam.scripts/ssh_alert.sh
EOF

When you run it on the target machine and it terminates successfully, you should be good to go.
